# AddEventListener is not working inside $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, touch

I have the following part of code for a cordova application:

```
$('.shadow-slider').addEventListener("touchmove",function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    update();
     shadow = x+"px "+y+"px ";
     if (op != 1){
    if(op.length > 3){op=op.substring(0, 3);}
    color="rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+op+")";
   }
   else{
    color="rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
   }
   if (blur != 0){shadow += blur+"px ";}
   shadow += color;
   $('#object').css("text-shadow",shadow);
   $('#code-output').html("text-shadow:"+shadow+";");

   });
```

inside the $(document).ready() for some sliders.

html:

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="jumbotron text-center">
         <h1 class="text-center"><span class='text-warning'>Text Shadow Generator V1.0</span></h1>
         <p>Create awesome text shadow with pure CSS3.</p>
       </div>
       <div id="sliders">
           <div class="row text-center">
             <div class="col-md-4">
             <h1>X-axis</h1>
             <input type="range" id="x" min="-10" max="10" step="1" value="0" class='shadow-slider'>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
               <h1>Y-axis</h1>
             <input type="range" id="y" min="-10" max="10" step="1" value="0" class='shadow-slider'>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
               <h1>Blur</h1>
             <input type="range" id="blur" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0" class='shadow-slider'>
             </div>
           </div>
           <!--End for shadow axis and blur sliders-->
           <div class="container"  style="margin-top:1em;"><p id="object">All text shadows will be applied here</p></div>
           <div class="row text-center">
             <div class="col-md-3">
               <h1>Red</h1>
             <input type="range" id="red" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" class='shadow-slider'>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3">
               <h1>Green</h1>
             <input type="range" id="green" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" class='shadow-slider'>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3">
               <h1>Blue</h1>
             <input type="range" id="blue" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" class='shadow-slider'>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3">
               <h1>Opacity</h1>
             <input type="range" id="o" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" class='shadow-slider'>
             </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

The problem is that when using jquery the  addEventListener method the touchmove is not working.Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addEventListener` is not a function in jQuery, you can replace this by :

```
$('.shadow-slider').on("touchmove",function(e){
  // your code here
});
```

`addEventListener` is for pure JS :

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
  // your code here
});
```

or for a specific html tag with an ID

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
  // your code here
});
```